# Getting the parent of parent view?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I use a `CollectionView` in my app, which of course has a `CollectionViewCell`, In the `CollectionViewCell`, I have a `StackView`, which has buttons in it. When tapping one of the buttons, I call a method which needs to get the cell that the button belongs to. I tried getting the `Sender`(the button) and then use `Sender.superview`, but it gives me the `StackView`, and `Sender.superview.superview` didn't work. How can I get the current cell that the button is in?

[image]

Marked in Red, is the `StackView` where the button is, and in Pink is the button I click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a more scalable approach. I would add a closure `var action: (() -> Void)?` to your custom `CollectionViewCell`, and in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, assign the action. To avoid memory retain cycle, don't forget to `unowned self` or `weak self`. In your `CollectionViewCell`, make an action function that would run `action?()`.

So it would be like:

```swift
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var action: (() -> Void)?

  @objc func buttonWasTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    action?()
  }

  ...
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonWasTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
  ...
}
```

and in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`:

```swift
  cell.action = { [unowned self] in /* Do something with self and the cell. */ }
```

====

EDIT:

The following example demonstrates a minimal example of using the above approach:

```swift
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var action: (() -> Void)?
  var votes = 0 {
    didSet { button.setTitle("\(votes)", for: .normal) }
  }

  private lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    // Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to programmatically setup layout
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    button.setTitle("\(votes)", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonWasTouched), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
  }()

  @objc private func buttonWasTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    action?()
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(button)
    // Programmatially setting layout constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
      button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
      button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
    ])
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    // Programatically register CollectionViewCell
    collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.action = { cell.votes += 1 }
    return cell
  }
}
```

If you run the code, each cells will have a button, which increments its number when touched.

Comment: Thanks, If I have two buttons, like upvote and downvote, do I need to check which one was pressed in cell.action {....} ? I will look more into that but I don't really get it no, cell.action will only do one thing, for example, upvoting a post, but if I want to click the delete or downvote button, what would happen?

Comment: If you have multiple buttons, add multiple closure properties like deleteAction: () -> Void, upvoteAction, etc

Comment: I tried this, and this is not working for me, I press the button but nothing happens, the button won't get the touch event at all.

Comment: See the EDIT. It demonstrates how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I had but it still didn’t work.

Comment: @JohnDoah But the above example works. Your problem may be caused by other issues. Can you debug it? To help you, you need to provide some code.

Comment: Sure, I really appreciate your help! I’m not near my computer at the moment, I will upload the code later today. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoah Good. If you make a change, let me know in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to reply, anyway, thank you so much. It is all working now. thanks again!